# Lottie animation is very small compared to it's container in react native

Tags: javascript, animation, react-native, lottie

I have an on click animation that is working perfectly, but I can't get the actual animated element to be more "zoomed" in. It looks like this:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import { Animated, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import Animation from 'lottie-react-native';

    // a bunch of code here
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={this.animate}
        underlayColor="transparent"
      >
        <Animation
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            width: 150,
            height: 150,
          }}
          source={favoriteHeart}
          progress={this.state.progress}
        />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
```

there's nothing funny going on with the parent View, so I'm really confused as to why the heart isn't taking the full width and height of the Animation view. This also makes placing this element next to either icons difficult.

Comment: Its because the actual JSON file has a lot of padding around it. I am struggling with this myself. Seems like no other way then to edit it in AE

Answer (score 0):

You can try add some properties of Lottie Animation:

```
<Animation
   style={{
       backgroundColor: 'red',
       width: 150,
       height: 150,
   }}
   source={favoriteHeart}
   progress={this.state.progress}
   resizeMode = 'cover'
 />
```